# SQL Server select query - conditional JOIN

Tags: sql-server, select

I have this query, but I want to only join `PostageRules` and `PostageGroups` if `p.delivery` has a value of -1

To clarify, I only want one delivery value, if `p.delivery` is -1 then we need to get the `po.delivery` value from the `PostageRules` table. At the moment the query gets the `po.delivery` regardless of the value of `p.delivery`

Is this possible to achieve in a single query?

```
SELECT  
   p.id as prod_id, p.delivery as delivery, 
   po.delivery AS delivery 
FROM 
   products AS p 
LEFT JOIN 
   PostageRules AS po ON p.shopkeeper = po.shopkeeper
LEFT JOIN 
   PostageGroups  AS pg ON po.groupID = pg.id
        AND po.minQty <= 1
        AND po.maxQty >= 1
        AND po.minPrice <= p.Price
        AND po.maxPrice >= p.Price
        AND po.minWeight <= p.weight
        AND po.maxWeight >= p.weight                
WHERE 
    (p.id = '32323') 
ORDER BY 
    po.preference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.id as prod_id, ISNULL(po.delivery, p.delivery) AS delivery 
    FROM products AS p 
    LEFT JOIN PostageRules AS po ON p.shopkeeper = po.shopkeeper and p.delivery = -1
    LEFT JOIN PostageGroups  AS pg ON po.groupID = pg.id and p.delivery = -1
    AND po.minQty <= 1
    AND po.maxQty >= 1
    AND po.minPrice <= p.Price
    AND po.maxPrice >= p.Price
    AND po.minWeight <= p.weight
    AND po.maxWeight >= p.weight                
    WHERE (p.id = '32323') ORDER BY po.preference
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  p.id as prod_id, p.delivery as delivery, CASE WHEN p.delivery=-1 then po.delivery else null end AS delivery 
        FROM products AS p 
        LEFT JOIN PostageRules AS po ON p.shopkeeper = po.shopkeeper
        LEFT JOIN PostageGroups  AS pg ON po.groupID = pg.id
        AND po.minQty <= 1
        AND po.maxQty >= 1
        AND po.minPrice <= p.Price
        AND po.maxPrice >= p.Price
        AND po.minWeight <= p.weight
        AND po.maxWeight >= p.weight                
        WHERE (p.id = '32323') ORDER BY po.preference
```